# Git rev list empty branch until current commit

Tags: git, github, githooks

I am writing a pre-receive hook. My remote branch doesn't have any commits yet. My local branch has several commits.

In the hook, I am not able to get all the commits from empty branch until recent commits. I tried 
`git rev-list <recent-commit>`
`git rev-list 4b825d..<recent-commit>`

as per [link](https://gist.github.com/lucaswerkmeister/08eb5e54db95d17f42b1) (line #32).

Comment: Line 32 in your link reads, in its entirety, `remote_sha=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904; # hash of the empty tree` (there is no occurrence of `git rev-list` here). That aside, in Git there is no such thing as an empty branch, so your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: Am referring to empty tree. I am using github and there's no such thing like "4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904" as per https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/355.

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense.  But the empty *tree* is not a branch, and is not a commit: it's a *tree*. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452 for details. Since it is not a commit it cannot be used with `git rev-list`.